# Git gc displays error "Could not read commit"

Tags: git

I'm having problem with my git repository. Git gui always pops up with loose object warning and when I let it compress it, popup appears next time git gui is started. I've tried executing `git gui` in console and here is the output:

```
$ git gc
error: Could not read 89acec6cd486753b5bbbcf6239f4cf39ab20c6a8
error: Could not read 4f0ce06bd472abcef5eef1ac9a780f2b2fb7d56f
error: Could not read 44e02cd1a9e12b9e6a2ad0b1f6dc062d1d25faac
error: Could not read e503215228feca3e4243e94b07c0714edc5b48ff
error: Could not read 4620c2776e1de834a5d5a56d711ff9b2e27699b7
Counting objects: 189655, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38260/38260), done.
Writing objects: 100% (189655/189655), done.
Total 189655 (delta 142194), reused 189655 (delta 142194)
error: Could not read 89acec6cd486753b5bbbcf6239f4cf39ab20c6a8
error: Could not read 4f0ce06bd472abcef5eef1ac9a780f2b2fb7d56f
error: Could not read 44e02cd1a9e12b9e6a2ad0b1f6dc062d1d25faac
error: Could not read e503215228feca3e4243e94b07c0714edc5b48ff
error: Could not read 4620c2776e1de834a5d5a56d711ff9b2e27699b7
Checking connectivity: 199676, done.
```

How to fix that?

`git show 89acec6cd486753b5bbbcf6239f4cf39ab20c6a8` results with `fatal: bad object 89acec6cd486753b5bbbcf6239f4cf39ab20c6a8` and `git fsck --full` with lots of dangling commits.

I'm using git v2.4.1

Thank you for all answers!

EDIT: I cloned my repository anew and copied .git folder into my tree and everything is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try anything below, please make a whole backup of everything in your project.

Since there's only five corrupted git objects, I suppose that they were all added in a single `git add`. If that's the case, you can try to search for a commit that points to a tree, that has these objects. If they are in a single commit, it's possible to manually delete that commit and reset branch heads to the last viable commit (if the corrupted belonged to any branches).

If a corrupted commit belongs to any branch, its removal will lead to a loss of latest git history. But you can use backed-up code to restore at least what's in your working tree now.

UPD:
Ah, sorry. Did not catch about dangling commits. So the history is damaged badly. Indeed, only 5 objects are broken. Those could be some long-unchanged files or folders, since they're present in many commits. What if files and folders for those git-objects are still present (and give the same SHAs)?

1. Copy all non-git files into another folder.
2. `git init; git add --all; git commit -m'message'`
3. Look at objects with SHAs of the broken one. For every one found replace a broken with a newly created one.

Comment: I've cloned my repository on another computer with same git version (2.4.1) and git gc does not report errors there. However, hashes reported by git gc on my computer do not exist there. It appears that only my clone of git is damaged. Is there a way to repair it (force clone or something similar)? If nothing helps, I will try cloning repository anew. Fortunately there are no local changes that are not pushed to remote.

Comment: Maybe clone it back now?

Comment: I cloned it anew and copied .git folder into my tree and everything is OK now.

Comment: So, git clone seems to sanitize a repo.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know why repo was corrupted. Fortunately only my local copy was corrupted so I was able to restore .git from another clone.